# what does it mean by "but as several"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, american-english

I am trying to read this sentence, but the part in bold is not clear to me.

> Many applications start based on monolithic architecture, **but as several** unforeseen requirements surfaced, can be slowly revamped to microservices that interact over an older monolithic architecture through APIs.

https://medium.com/coding-in-simple-english/what-are-microservices-ecbced182805

Comment: It seems to be incomplete:  not a whole sentence. Can you put down the exact quote, or a pointer to the source?

Comment: The *minimal* change required to enforce "grammaticality" here is simply to change Past Tense *[unforeseen requirements] **surfaced*** to Present Tense ***surface***. Alternatively, switch ***all*** the Present Tense verb forms to Past Tense *(**started, could be, interacted**)*.

Comment: *but as several* is not a phrase on its own.  *but* is a conjunction, used normally, joining *start* with *can be revamped*.  The second clause has a dependent context-clause, *as requirements surfaced*.  The whole would be clearer, I think, if the comma before *but* were moved after.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a well worded sentence, in my opinion.

It is saying "Many applications are originally designed with a monolithic architecture.  However, there are often requirements that were not understood when the design was started.  As more and more of these requirements are discovered, the application slowly changes to one based on microservices"

Does that help?